# Estou desenvolvendo um site pelo Google Sites Classic, porém alguns gráficos de tabela não estão carregando.

Tags: google-sites

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Todos os gráficos que estou inserindo no site são importados do google spreadsheet. Os gráficos de colunas carregam normalmente. Todavia, os gráficos de tabela (importados da mesma planilha), a partir de um certo momento do desenvolvimento do site, começaram a não carregar mais, acusando o seguinte erro:

docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/3/d/1ULeD7yyzez_yIr27rHJWOSBlfNoeqdXJGidzzQL-Lcc/embed/oimg?newCharts=false&oid=null Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

```html
<html><head><script src="https://docs.google.com/static/spreadsheets2/ad4d0544de/ritz_tviz_charts/3C661C56B022016D7C601800856DA369.cache.js"></script></head><body style="padding:0;margin:0"><div id="embed_chart" style="width:1150;height:500;overflow:hidden;"><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/spreadsheets2/ad4d0544de/ritz_tviz_charts/ritz_tviz_charts.nocache.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">var chartData = { };chartData['chart'] = null;function initCharts() {chartData['chart'] = {'chartId': 'chart', 'elementId': 'embed_chart', 'chartJson': '{\x22view\x22:{\x22columns\x22:[0,1,{\x22label\x22:\x22\x22,\x22properties\x22:{\x22role\x22:\x22annotation\x22},\x22sourceColumn\x22:2},3,{\x22label\x22:\x22\x22,\x22properties\x22:{\x22role\x22:\x22annotation\x22},\x22sourceColumn\x22:4},5,{\x22label\x22:\x22\x22,\x22properties\x22:{\x22role\x22:\x22annotation\x22},\x22sourceColumn\x22:6},7,{\x22label\x22:\x22\x22,\x22properties\x22:{\x22role\x22:\x22annotation\x22},\x22sourceColumn\x22:8},9,{\x22label\x22:\x22\x22,\x22properties\x22:{\x22role\x22:\x22annotation\x22},\x22sourceColumn\x22:10},11]},\x22chartName\x22:\x22Gráfico do Google\x22,\x22dataTable\x22:{\x22rows\x22:[{\x22c\x22:[{\x22v\x22:\x22VEREADOR ADIR PRETTO\x22},{\x22v\x22:5556,\x22f\x22:\x22R$5.556,00\x22},{\x22v\x22:\x22VEREADOR ADIR PRETTO\x22},{\x22v\x22:5556,\x22f\x22:\x22R$5.556,00\x22},{\x22v\x22:\x22VEREADOR ADIR PRETTO\x22},{\x22v\x22:5556,\x22f\x22:\x22R$5.556,00\x22},{\x22v\x22:\x22VEREADOR ADIR PRETTO\x22},{\x22v\x22:5556,\x22f\x22:\x22R$5.556,00\x22},{\x22v\x22:\x22VEREADOR ADIR PRETTO\x22},{\x22v\x22:5556,\x22f\x22:\x22R$5.556,00\x22},{\x22v\x22:\x22VEREADOR ADIR PRETTO\x22},{\x22v\x22:5556,\x22f\x22:\x22R$5.556,00\x22}]},{\x22c\x22:[{\x22v\x22:\x22CHEFE DE GABINETE - RODRIGO OLIVEIRA\x22},{\x22v\x22:0,\x22f\x22:\x22R$0,00\x22},{\x22v\x22:\x22CHEFE DE GABINETE - RODRIGO OLIVEIRA\x22},{\x22v\x22:0,\x22f\x22:\x22R$0,00\x22},{\x22v\x22:\x22CHEFE DE GABINETE - RODRIGO OLIVEIRA\x22},{\x22v\x22:2816.42,\x22f\x22:\x22R$2.816,42\x22},{\x22v\x22:\x22CHEFE DE GABINETE - RODRIGO OLIVEIRA\x22},{\x22v\x22:2816.42,\x22f\x22:\x22R$2.816,42\x22},{\x22v\x22:\x22CHEFE DE GABINETE - RODRIGO OLIVEIRA\x22},{\x22v\x22:2816.32,\x22f\x22:\x22R$2.816,32\x22},{\x22v\x22:\x22CHEFE DE GABINETE - RODRIGO OLIVEIRA\x22},{\x22v\x22:2816.32,\x22f\x22:\x22R$2.816,32\x22}]},{\x22c\x22:[{\x22v\x22:\x22ASSESSOR - JOÃO CARLOS FIGUEIREDO\x22},{\x22v\x22:0,\x22f\x22:\x22R$0,00\x22},{\x22v\x22:\x22ASSESSOR - JOÃO CARLOS FIGUEIREDO\x22},{\x22v\x22:0,\x22f\x22:\x22R$0,00\x22},{\x22v\x22:\x22ASSESSOR - JOÃO CARLOS FIGUEIREDO\x22},{\x22v\x22:1247.35,\x22f\x22:\x22R$1.247,35\x22},{\x22v\x22:\x22ASSESSOR - JOÃO CARLOS FIQUEIREDO\x22},{\x22v\x22:1681.22,\x22f\x22:\x22R$1.681,22\x22},{\x22v\x22:\x22ASSESSOR - JOÃO CARLOS FIGUEIREDO\x22},{\x22v\x22:1681.22,\x22f\x22:\x22R$1.681,22\x22},{\x22v\x22:\x22ASSESSOR - JOÃO CARLOS FIGUEIREDO\x22},{\x22v\x22:1681.22,\x22f\x22:\x22R$1.681,22\x22}]}],\x22cols\x22:[{\x22id\x22:\x22A\x22,\x22label\x22:\x22\x22,\x22type\x22:\x22string\x22},{\x22pattern\x22:\x22\\\x22R$\\\x22#,##0.00\x22,\x22id\x22:\x22B\x22,\x22label\x22:\x22JANEIRO (2017)\x22,\x22type\x22:\x22number\x22},{\x22id\x22:\x22C\x22,\x22label\x22:\x22\x22,\x22type\x22:\x22string\x22},{\x22pattern\x22:\x22\\\x22R$\\\x22#,##0.00\x22,\x22id\x22:\x22D\x22,\x22label\x22:\x22FEVEREIRO (2017)\x22,\x22type\x22:\x22number\x22},{\x22id\x22:\x22E\x22,\x22label\x22:\x22\x22,\x22type\x22:\x22string\x22},{\x22pattern\x22:\x22\\\x22R$\\\x22#,##0.00\x22,\x22id\x22:\x22F\x22,\x22label\x22:\x22MARÇO (2017)\x22,\x22type\x22:\x22number\x22},{\x22id\x22:\x22G\x22,\x22label\x22:\x22\x22,\x22type\x22:\x22string\x22},{\x22pattern\x22:\x22\\\x22R$\\\x22#,##0.00\x22,\x22id\x22:\x22H\x22,\x22label\x22:\x22ABRIL (2017)\x22,\x22type\x22:\x22number\x22},{\x22id\x22:\x22I\x22,\x22label\x22:\x22\x22,\x22type\x22:\x22string\x22},{\x22pattern\x22:\x22\\\x22R$\\\x22#,##0.00\x22,\x22id\x22:\x22J\x22,\x22label\x22:\x22MAIO (2017)\x22,\x22type\x22:\x22number\x22},{\x22id\x22:\x22K\x22,\x22label\x22:\x22\x22,\x22type\x22:\x22string\x22},{\x22pattern\x22:\x22\\\x22R$\\\x22#,##0.00\x22,\x22id\x22:\x22L\x22,\x22label\x22:\x22JUNHO (2017)\x22,\x22type\x22:\x22number\x22}]},\x22options\x22:{\x22hAxis\x22:{\x22useFormatFromData\x22:true,\x22viewWindow\x22:{}},\x22vAxes\x22:[{\x22useFormatFromData\x22:true,\x22minValue\x22:null,\x22maxValue\x22:null,\x22viewWindow\x22:{\x22min\x22:null,\x22max\x22:null}},{\x22useFormatFromData\x22:true,\x22minValue\x22:null,\x22maxValue\x22:null,\x22viewWindow\x22:{\x22min\x22:null,\x22max\x22:null}}],\x22legend\x22:\x22right\x22,\x22width\x22:\x221150\x22,\x22legacyScatterChartLabels\x22:true,\x22booleanRole\x22:\x22certainty\x22,\x22height\x22:\x22500\x22},\x22chartType\x22:\x22Table\x22,\x22state\x22:{},\x22isDefaultVisualization\x22:false}', 'fallbackUri': '\/spreadsheets\/d\/1ULeD7yyzez_yIr27rHJWOSBlfNoeqdXJGidzzQL-Lcc\/embed\/oimg?newCharts\x3dfalse\x26oid\x3dnull', 'chart': null, 'interactionState': ritz_tviz_charts.ChartsExportApi.newInteractionState()}; drawNewChart( chartData['chart'], 'pt_BR', 1150.0 , 500.0 );}function drawNewChart(chartState, spreadsheetLocale, width, height) {var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'); var chartElement = document.getElementById(chartState.elementId); width = width == 0 ? window.innerWidth : width; height = height == 0 ? window.innerHeight : height; canvas.width = width; canvas.height = height; canvas.id = 'chart_' + chartState.chartId; chartState.chart = ritz_tviz_charts.ChartsExportApi.buildAndLayoutChartFromGvizWrapper( canvas.getContext('2d'), chartState.chartJson, width, height, spreadsheetLocale); if (chartState.chart && ritz_tviz_charts.ChartsExportApi.renderChart( canvas.getContext('2d'), chartState.chart, chartState.interactionState)) {canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) { handleMouseEvent(e, canvas, chartState); }); canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) { handleMouseEvent(e, canvas, chartState); }); canvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) { handleMouseEvent(e, canvas, chartState); }); chartElement.appendChild(canvas);} else {var img = document.createElement('img'); img.setAttribute('src', chartState.fallbackUri); img.setAttribute('width', width); img.setAttribute('height', height); img.id = 'chart_' + chartState.chartId; chartElement.appendChild(img);}chartState.tooltipRenderer = new TooltipRenderer(); chartState.tooltipRenderer.render(chartElement);}function layoutChart(chartState, canvas) {ritz_tviz_charts.ChartsExportApi.layoutChart( canvas.getContext('2d'), chartState.chart, chartState.interactionState, canvas.width, canvas.height);}function renderChart(chartState, canvas) {ritz_tviz_charts.ChartsExportApi.renderChart( canvas.getContext('2d'), chartState.chart, chartState.interactionState);}function handleMouseEvent(e, canvas, chartState) {var x = e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left; var y = e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top; var oldState = chartState.interactionState; chartState.interactionState = (e.type == 'click') ? ritz_tviz_charts.ChartsExportApi.onClick(chartState.chart, oldState, x, y) : ritz_tviz_charts.ChartsExportApi.onMouseMove(chartState.chart, oldState, x, y); if(ritz_tviz_charts.ChartsExportApi.isLayoutNeeded( chartState.chart, oldState, chartState.interactionState)) {layoutChart(chartState, canvas);}renderChart(chartState, canvas); if (chartState.tooltipRenderer) {if (e.type == 'mouseleave') {chartState.tooltipRenderer.hide();} else {ritz_tviz_charts.ChartsExportApi.refreshTooltip( chartState.chart, chartState.tooltipRenderer, chartState.interactionState);}}}function onChartsExportApiLoad() {initCharts();}

var TooltipRenderer = function() {
  this.content_ = document.createElement('div');
  this.content_.style.display = 'none';
  this.content_.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
  this.content_.style.border = '1px solid #c1c1d1';
  this.content_.style.borderRadius = '2px';
  this.content_.style.color = '#424242';
  this.content_.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif';
  this.content_.style.fontSize = '13px';
  this.content_.style.fontWeight = '500';
  this.content_.style.padding = '6px 12px';
  this.content_.style.position = 'absolute';
  this.content_.style.zIndex = 3;

  this.labeledValues_ = [];
};

TooltipRenderer.prototype.showAt = function(x, y) {
  this.content_.style.left = (x + 10) + 'px';
  this.content_.style.top = (y + 10) + 'px';
  this.content_.style.display = 'initial';
};

TooltipRenderer.prototype.hide = function() {
  this.content_.style.display = 'none';
};

TooltipRenderer.prototype.forValue = function(value) {
  this.forLabeledValue(value);
};

TooltipRenderer.prototype.forLabeledValue = function(value, label, color) {
  this.labeledValues_ = [];
  this.addLabeledValue(value, label, color);
  this.prepareLabeledValuesRenderer();
};

TooltipRenderer.prototype.addLabeledValue = function (value, label, color) {
  this.labeledValues_.push({'label': label, 'value': value, 'color': color});
};

TooltipRenderer.prototype.prepareLabeledValuesRenderer = function() {
  this.content_.innerHTML = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < this.labeledValues_.length; i++) {
    var labeledValue = this.labeledValues_[i];
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    if (labeledValue.label) {
      var label = document.createElement('span');
      label.textContent = labeledValue.label + ': ';
      div.appendChild(label);
    }
    if (labeledValue.value) {
      var value = document.createElement('span');

      if (labeledValue.color) {
        value.style.color = toCssColor(labeledValue.color);
      }

      value.textContent = labeledValue.value;
      div.appendChild(value);
    }
    this.content_.appendChild(div);
  }
  this.labeledValues_ = [];
};

TooltipRenderer.prototype.render = function(parent) {
  parent.appendChild(this.content_);
};

function toCssColor(color) {
  const b = color & 0xFF;
  const g = (color >>> 8) & 0xFF;
  const r = (color >>> 16) & 0xFF;
  const a = ((color >>> 24) & 0xFF) / 255;
  return 'rgba(' + [r, g, b, a].join(',') + ')';
}
function chartMessageFormat(str, args) {
  return str.replace(/\{\{|\}\}|\{(\d+)\}/g, function (m, n) {
    if (m == "{{") { return "{"; }
    if (m == "}}") { return "}"; }
    return args[n];
  });
  }var __chartmessages = { };__chartmessages['CALL_CHART_REQUIRES_MINIMUM_COLUMNS'] = function() {var args = []; for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {args[i] = arguments[i];}return chartMessageFormat('É necessário pelo menos {0} colunas, mas há apenas {1}.', args);};__chartmessages['CALL_CHART_COLUMN_MUST_BE_TEXT'] = function() {var args = []; for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {args[i] = arguments[i];}return chartMessageFormat('A coluna {0} precisa conter texto.', args);};__chartmessages['MSG_CHART_HISTOGRAM_INVALID_BUCKET_SIZE'] = 'Tamanho de intervalo inválido, precisa ser maior que zero.';__chartmessages['MSG_CHART_TREE_MAP_MULTIPLE_ROOTS'] = 'Dois nós raiz foram encontrados. Apenas um é permitido.';__chartmessages['CALL_CHART_COLUMN_MUST_BE_NUMERIC'] = function() {var args = []; for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {args[i] = arguments[i];}return chartMessageFormat('A coluna {0} precisa ser numérica.', args);};__chartmessages['CALL_CHART_HISTOGRAM_COUNT_LABEL'] = function() {var args = []; for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {args[i] = arguments[i];}return chartMessageFormat('{0} (contagem)', args);};__chartmessages['MSG_CHART_HISTOGRAM_COUNT'] = '(contagem)';__chartmessages['MSG_CHART_HISTOGRAM_INVALID_BUCKET_PERCENTILE'] = 'Percentil de intervalo inválido, precisa estar entre 0% e 100%.';__chartmessages['MSG_CHART_NO_DATA_DISPLAY'] = 'Não há dados';__chartmessages['CALL_CHART_LEGEND_MORE_ENTRIES'] = function() {var args = []; for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {args[i] = arguments[i];}return chartMessageFormat('Mais {0}', args);};__chartmessages['CALL_CHART_TREE_MAP_MISSING_PARENT'] = function() {var args = []; for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {args[i] = arguments[i];}return chartMessageFormat('Não foi possível encontrar a linha pai com o marcador: {0}', args);};__chartmessages['CALL_CHART_TREE_MAP_DUPLICATE_NODE'] = function() {var args = []; for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {args[i] = arguments[i];}return chartMessageFormat('Duas entradas foram encontradas com o mesmo marcador: {0}', args);};__chartmessages['MSG_CHART_INTERNAL_ERROR'] = 'Ocorreu um erro interno ao renderizar o gráfico.';</script><img src="/spreadsheets/d/1ULeD7yyzez_yIr27rHJWOSBlfNoeqdXJGidzzQL-Lcc/embed/oimg?newCharts=false&amp;oid=null" width="1150" height="500" id="chart_chart"><div style="display: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 209); border-radius: 2px; color: rgb(66, 66, 66); font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 500; padding: 6px 12px; position: absolute; z-index: 3;"></div></div><iframe id="ritz_tviz_charts" tabindex="-1" style="position: absolute; width: 0px; height: 0px; border: none; left: -1000px; top: -1000px;"></iframe></body></html>
```